# global text into a link drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view and has created fields like a title and gglobal text that contains an image.

The field title has enabled the option " Link This field to the original the piece of content" that makes it a link to the node , but want to convert the picture also a link to when you click on the image leads to the url the node .

how could I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the rewrite option to make image field as link in drupal views with replacement pattern.